# Are there alternative languages to python for controlling a PiGlow?

Tags: python

I've seen lots of references to python for controlling the display on a PiGlow.  Are there any alternative languages available?  I could learn python, but if there are others I might use them instead.  My preferences would be bash shell script and javascript.

Comment: It would be hard to find a language that can not interface RPi's i2c via some library. I mostly use Lazarus/FreePascal and it has no problems at all with I2C (I think I can choose between 3 libraries for I2C access).

Answer (score 1):

The PiGlow [store page](http://shop.pimoroni.com/products/piglow#.UtgaVDd_vh8) lists languages that have libraries for the PiGlow.

But since the driver IC is interfaced using i2c, you could use any language that allows you to use i2c, [eLinux](http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices) has a good page on this.

Comment: There's a node.js library on that list, so the OP should be able to use javascript.